# Correct form of ‘despise’

Tags: grammar

I know that in English one can say ‘filled with loathing for…’ or ‘ filled with disgust for…’. Similarly is it correct to say ‘filled with despising for…’ or should it be “despisement” ? What is the correct usage?

Comment: There isn't no such noun in common use. Dictionaries give _despite_ in this sense, but I have never encountered _despite_ as a noun: it is now only used as a preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun related to *despise* is *despite*:
[Marriam-Webster *despite*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despite)
noun:
1 : the feeling or attitude of despising someone or something : contempt
2 : malice, spite

Both forms come from Latin *despicere*, to look down on.

(This meaning is distinct from the meaning of *despite* as a preposition.)

There is also *spite*, which M-W says is a shortened form of *despite*, but it has a slightly different meaning:
[Merriam-Webster *spite*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spite)
1 : petty ill will or hatred with the disposition to irritate, annoy, or thwart
2 : an instance of spite